# Summing rows of values conditionally in Excel / Google Sheets

Tags: excel, google-sheets

I have a spreadsheet that looks like this:

```
NAME     HOURS ESTIMATED FOR TASK
================================
Bob          7
Jim          6
Bob          1
Sue          10
```

What I want to be able to do is to sum the total number of hours that each worker will have to spend on all tasks:

```
NAME     HOURS ESTIMATED FOR TASK
================================
Bob          7
Jim          6
Bob          1
Sue          10

TOTALS
Bob          8
Jim          6
Sue          10
```

I assume that I would combine some kind of `HLOOKUP` and `SUMIF` to complete the TOTALS section, but I'm not sure. How would I complete this kind of summation?

Comment: `SUMIF` is a good way to tackle it.

Comment: sorry here, was looking for google-spreadsheet mostly, turns out it is most efficiently handled by using arrays. I will write up a solution. I do my best to accept correct answers, I probably do not accept my own answers very often.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe:

```
=query(A2:B5,"select A, sum(B) group by A ")
```